# Why do keyword arguments to a class definition reappear after they were removed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

I created a metaclass that defines the `__prepare__` method, which is supposed to consume a specific keyword in the class definition, like this:

```
class M(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metaclass, name, bases, **kwds):
        print('in M.__prepare__:')
        print(f'  {metaclass=}\n  {name=}\n'
              f'  {bases=}\n  {kwds=}\n  {id(kwds)=}')
        if 'for_prepare' not in kwds:
            return super().__prepare__(name, bases, **kwds)
        arg = kwds.pop('for_prepare')
        print(f'  arg popped for prepare: {arg}')
        print(f'  end of prepare: {kwds=} {id(kwds)=}')
        return super().__prepare__(name, bases, **kwds)

    def __new__(metaclass, name, bases, ns, **kwds):
        print('in M.__new__:')
        print(f'  {metaclass=}\n  {name=}\n'
              f'  {bases=}\n  {ns=}\n  {kwds=}\n  {id(kwds)=}')
        return super().__new__(metaclass, name, bases, ns, **kwds)


class A(metaclass=M, for_prepare='xyz'):
    pass
```

When I run it, the `for_prepare` keyword argument in the definition of class A reappears in `__new__` (and later in `__init_subclass__`, where it causes an error):

```
$ python3 ./weird_prepare.py
in M.__prepare__:
  metaclass=<class '__main__.M'>
  name='A'
  bases=()
  kwds={'for_prepare': 'xyz'}
  id(kwds)=140128409916224
  arg popped for prepare: xyz
  end of prepare: kwds={} id(kwds)=140128409916224
in M.__new__:
  metaclass=<class '__main__.M'>
  name='A'
  bases=()
  ns={'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'A'}
  kwds={'for_prepare': 'xyz'}
  id(kwds)=140128409916224
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./weird_prepare.py", line 21, in <module>
    class A(metaclass=M, for_prepare='xyz'):
  File "./weird_prepare.py", line 18, in __new__
    return super().__new__(metaclass, name, bases, ns, **kwds)
TypeError: __init_subclass__() takes no keyword arguments
```

As you can see the `for_prepare` item is removed from the dict, and the dict that is passed to `__new__` is the same object that was passed to `__prepare__` and the same object that the `for_prepare` item was popped from, but in `__new__` it reappeared!  Why does a keyword that was deleted from the dict get added back in?

Comment: You got. answers to what is happening, but none seems to touch on the topic of the proper way to avoid the error your are getting: `__init_subclass__`should always be written in a collaborative way, receiving **kwargs, and calling supper with whatever args it does not consume. Unfortunatelly `__init_subclass__` aparently has to be set to any class with a metaclass taking KW params and consume those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> and the dict that is passed to **new** is the same object that was passed to **prepare**

Unfortunately, this is where you are wrong.

Python only recycles the same object id.

If you create a new dict inside `__prepare__` you will notice the id of `kwds` changes in `__new__`.

```
class M(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metaclass, name, bases, **kwds):
        print('in M.__prepare__:')
        print(f'  {metaclass=}\n  {name=}\n'
              f'  {bases=}\n  {kwds=}\n  {id(kwds)=}')
        if 'for_prepare' not in kwds:
            return super().__prepare__(name, bases, **kwds)
        arg = kwds.pop('for_prepare')
        x = {} # <<< create a new dict
        print(f'  arg popped for prepare: {arg}')
        print(f'  end of prepare: {kwds=} {id(kwds)=}')
        return super().__prepare__(name, bases, **kwds)

    def __new__(metaclass, name, bases, ns, **kwds):
        print('in M.__new__:')
        print(f'  {metaclass=}\n  {name=}\n'
              f'  {bases=}\n  {ns=}\n  {kwds=}\n  {id(kwds)=}')
        return super().__new__(metaclass, name, bases, ns, **kwds)


class A(metaclass=M, for_prepare='xyz'):
    pass
```

Output:

```
in M.__prepare__:
  metaclass=<class '__main__.M'>
  name='A'
  bases=()
  kwds={'for_prepare': 'xyz'}
  id(kwds)=2595838763072
  arg popped for prepare: xyz
  end of prepare: kwds={} id(kwds)=2595838763072
in M.__new__:
  metaclass=<class '__main__.M'>
  name='A'
  bases=()
  ns={'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'A'}
  kwds={'for_prepare': 'xyz'}
  id(kwds)=2595836298496 # <<< id has changed now
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\nemetris\mpf\mpf.test\test_so4.py", line 22, in <module>
    class A(metaclass=M, for_prepare='xyz'):
  File "d:\nemetris\mpf\mpf.test\test_so4.py", line 19, in __new__ 
    return super().__new__(metaclass, name, bases, ns, **kwds)     
TypeError: A.__init_subclass__() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: So if Python passes a new dict with the class definition keyword arguments to `__new__`, if I want to pass a class definition keyword to `__prepare__`, I have to define `__new__` that does nothing but ignore that keyword?

Comment: Well, you are not really passing a dict as @MisterMiyagi pointed out. You are passing an upacked version of your dict that gets "packed back together" into a new dict by the called function. In your case the "old" dict just happens to be deleted from memory and the new dict is then created with the same id. So yes, if you want to get rid of a dictionary item in ``__new__`` you should remove it in ``__new__``. Or maybe you can change your class to actually pass a dict around instead of ``**kwargs``

Answer (score 4):

This is not an effect of metaclasses, but of `**kwargs`. Whenever a function is called with `**kwargs`, the current dict is unpacked *and not passed on*. Whenever a function receives `**kwargs`, *a new dict is created*.

In effect, when both of caller/callee use `**kwargs` then the dict seen by either is a *copy*.

Compare the setup of using `**kwargs` in isolation:

```py
def first(**kwargs):
    print(f"Popped 'some_arg': {kwargs.pop('some_arg')!r}")

def second(**kwargs):
    print(f"Got {kwargs} in the end")

def head(**kwargs):
    first(**kwargs)
    second(**kwargs)

head(a=2, b=3, some_arg="Watch this!", c=4)
# Popped 'some_arg': 'Watch this!'
# Got {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'some_arg': 'Watch this!', 'c': 4} in the end
```

Likewise, `__prepare__` and `__new__` are separately called when creating a `class`. Their `**kwargs` are shallow copies and neither adding nor removing items is visible to the other call.

Answer (score 1):

- don't send `**kwds` to `__new__`, it won't catch them after python 3.6 .

#### example

```
class M(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metaclass, name, bases, **kwds):
        # print('in M.__prepare__:')
        # print(f'  {metaclass}=\n  {name}=\n'
        #       f'  {bases}=\n  {kwds}=\n  {id(kwds)}=')
        if 'for_prepare' not in kwds:
            return super().__prepare__(name, bases, **kwds)
        # arg = kwds.pop('for_prepare')
        # print(f'  arg popped for prepare: {arg}')
        # print(f'  end of prepare: {kwds}= {id(kwds)}=')
        return super().__prepare__(name, bases, **kwds)

    def __new__(metaclass, name, bases, ns, **kwds):
        print('in M.__new__:')
        print(f'  metaclass = {metaclass}\n  name = {name}\n'
              f'  bases = {bases}\n  ns = {ns}\n  kwds = {kwds}\n  id_kwds = {id(kwds)}')
        return super().__new__(metaclass, name, bases, ns)


class A(metaclass=M, for_prepare='xyz'):
    pass

a = A()
```

#### result:

```
in M.__new__:
  metaclass = <class '__main__.M'>
  name = A
  bases = ()
  ns = {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'A'}
  kwds = {'for_prepare': 'xyz'}
  id_kwds = 2101285477256
```